# Arrays insert phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

i have elements in an array and I would like to put the values in a column but start inserting in cell 2. for example Column E start inserting E2 going down to E6.

Here is an example code I have tried:

```
  foreach($distinctresults as $distinctres)
  {
   $distinctnow[]=$distinctres;
  }
  for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$i,$distinctnow[$i]);
   }
```

if I add another loop starting with 2 to cater for the row number in E it throws a offset error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'd be how you adjust the cell references

```
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'. ($i + 1),$distinctnow[$i]);
                                                     ^^^^^^^^
```

but note that your $distinctnow array will actually have keys 0->5 (assuming 6 data points), and you're looping over 1->6, so you're missing an item. How about:

```
$i = 2;
foreach($distinctresults as $distinctres) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'. $i,$distinctres);
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$i+1,$distinctnow[$i]);
}
```